# Using named keys in a JS array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working through [The Principles of Object-Oriented Javascript](http://smile.amazon.com/Principles-Object-Oriented-JavaScript-Nicholas-Zakas/dp/1593275404/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1442157201&sr=8-1&keywords=object+oriented+javascript) and am confused with Zakas's use of a named key inside an array (as opposed to inside an object). See comment:

```
function EventTarget() {}

EventTarget.prototype = {

    constructor: EventTarget,

    addListener: function(type, listener) {

        if (!this.hasOwnProperty("_listeners")) {
            // Why isn't this: `this._listeners = {};`
            this._listeners = [];
        }

        if (typeof this._listeners[type] === "undefined") {
            this._listeners[type] = [];
        }

        this._listeners[type].push(listener);
    },

    // more stuff
}

var target = new EventTarget();
target.addListener("message", function(event) {
    console.log("Message is " + event.data);
});
```

His code works fine (as it does if you substitute the array for an object literal), but my understanding has been that you should use an object if you want to access the contents by name. From the [array article on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp):

> Many programming languages support arrays with named indexes.
>   Arrays with named indexes are called associative arrays (or hashes).
>   JavaScript does **not** support arrays with named indexes.
>   In JavaScript, **arrays** always use **numbered indexes**.

Is there a good reason that Zakas used an array like this? Can you please explain it? Alternatively, is this something I should submit to [the errata](https://www.nostarch.com/oojs#updates)?

Comment: This code is correct if `type` is integer

Comment: This code still works because it is setting properties on the array object, not in the actual array. Check `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this._listeners)` and then `Object.keys(this._listeners)`. `this._listeners` should be an object, not an array.

Comment: @hindmost: The code is correct (in that it's functional) even if `type` *isn't* an integer (and it seems pretty likely it won't be, much more likely to be a string like `"click"`).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Unless somebody passes the string `"length"` for `type`. Then exciting things happen.

Comment: @hindmost That's totally true, I edited the sample to show how type is set to `"message"`.

Comment: (Even if you switch to `{}` you have a problem if somebody passes the string `"hasOwnProperty"` for `type`.)

Comment: @RaymondChen: Indeed, which is why ES6 has `Map`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I meant that if `type` is integer, it would explain why `[]` is used

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only reason I can see is : confusing people. JavaScript doesn't enforce anything, really, and since everything is an object, you can do pretty much whatever you want. This guy is using an array to store named properties, but he could very well have used a function or anything else !

Edit : *almost* everything is an object (it would have occured to me that someone could try to set a property on `undefined`, since one of the most common errors in JavaScript is `TypeError : undefined is not an object`. *sighs* JavaScript, why are you doing this to us ?

Comment: "everything is an object". Not everything!

Comment: Undefined is not an object... `typeof undefined === "undefined"`

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a good reason that Zakas used an array like this?

From the quoted code, I can't think of one, no. He's not using the fact that `_listeners` refers to an array. It frankly just looks like a typo. Since it works (because JavaScript's normal arrays are objects), the typo wasn't caught. Well, until you caught it. :-)

Unless there's some code you haven't quoted which is then adding *array enries** to that array, there's no reason to use an array there (and arguably a couple of reasons not to).

* "array entry" = property whose key is an *array index*. So what's an "array index"? *"A String property name P is an array index if and only if `ToString(ToUint32(P))` is equal to P and `ToUint32(P)` is not equal to `232−1`."* ([spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array-exotic-objects))

Answer (score 3):

Arrays are just special objects....

```
a=[]
a[7]=9
a["abc"]=20
a["xxx"]=30
for (i in a) console.log("value",i,a[i])
```

Output;

```
value 7 9
value abc 20
value xxx 30
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm inclined to say it's a typo but in the off-chance it was intended, then the following is the only functional use-case I can come up with... (**warning:** may divide opinion).

Given that an observer/event pattern is a generic concept that could be applied to any object and the *"private"* (denoted by the underscore) `_listeners` property will likely never need to be known about by the target - then it's arguable that the data it contains is superfluous to the object itself.

That is to say, it's probably not desirable to transmit this kind of data should the target object be serialized.  The following example illustrates how the *JSON* serializer ignores the non-numeric array properties in `foo.baz` - similarly in your own example, all attached event data would be removed:

```
var foo = {
    bar: {},
    baz: []
};

foo.bar['p1'] = foo.baz['p1'] = 1;
foo.bar['p2'] = foo.baz['p2'] = 2;

console.log( JSON.stringify(foo) ); // {"bar":{"p1":1,"p2":2},"baz":[]}
```

Comment: Imma give you an upvote because damn dude, that's some lateral thinking right there. I don't think it's necessarily a good reason for abusing JS constructs, but it's thought-provoking.